# Transform geospatial data from decimal degrees to x,y coordinates using pyproj in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, python-3, pyproj

I have the following dataframe

```
 latitude  longitude             xx            yy
0  37.75153 -122.39447  553343.041098  4.178420e+06
1  37.75149 -122.39447  553343.069815  4.178415e+06
2  37.75149 -122.39447  553343.069815  4.178415e+06
3  37.75149 -122.39446  553343.950755  4.178415e+06
4  37.75144 -122.39449  553341.343829  4.178410e+06
```

where `latitude` and `longitude` are in `decimal degrees`

I am using this code to go from `latitude` & `longitude` to `xx` & `yy`.

```
from pyproj import Proj
pp = Proj(proj='utm', zone=10, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
xx, yy = pp(dt["longitude"].values, dt["latitude"].values)
```

The [documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/proj.html) of `pyproj` mentions:

> "Calling a Proj class instance with the arguments lon, lat will
>   convert lon/lat (in degrees) to x/y native map projection coordinates
>   (in meters)"

1) A very amateur question that I have is: Are the `degrees` that are
   mentioned in the documentation, the same as the `decimal` degrees ?
   If not, how can I go from one to another ?

2) Secondly I dont understand what these parameters of the function
  stand for

```
   proj='utm', zone=10, ellps='WGS84'
```

Any shred of light ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, yes, they are the same.

For #2, the UTM projection is a system of zones setup for the Transverse Mercator projection. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

The string you are using to define the UTM projection is a PROJ string an each parameter is defined here: https://proj.org/operations/projections/utm.html

`proj=utm` - tells PROJ that you are using the UTM projection

`zone=10` - says to use zone 10 for the UTM projection

`ellps=WGS84` - defines the ellipsoid to use